# Hitech C Syntax

Tags: c, syntax, hi-tech-c

Can someone explain me this syntax? It comes from the Hi Tech C include file

```
    /*  STATUS bits */
static volatile bit IRP     @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+7;
static volatile bit RP1     @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+6;
static volatile bit RP0     @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+5;
static volatile bit TO  @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+4;
static volatile bit PD  @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+3;
static volatile bit ZERO    @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+2;
static volatile bit DC      @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+1;
static volatile bit CARRY   @ (unsigned)&STATUS*8+0;
```

Comment: I guess is setting the exact "address" of each single bit in STATUS.

Comment: The non-standard `@` symbol is usually used for allocating a variable at a specific address. In this case, it seems to be used to name individual bits of a bit field.

`(unsigned)&STATUS` will give a pointer to unsigned integer, and an integer is several bytes wide. Then for some reason they multiply this address by 8 and add an offset. 

It is always best to avoid non-standard crap headers like this: if possible, roll out your own register definitions instead, preferably by using `#define` and the bitwise operators.

Comment: There is a former question that answers about the "@" symbol. I don't get the multiplication.

Comment: Olaf states that the compiler probably uses an 11bit word where the upper 8 bits hold the address while the lower 3 bits hold the bit number. This is NOT stated in the Hi tech C manual for 10/12/16 series but I came to the conclusion that this is the most probable explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume these are peripherail hardware registers. The `bit` type and `@` are non-standard. `@` places them at absolute addresses given by `STATUS`. `bit` tells the compiler that the addresses are actually single bits, so it possibly has to use appropriate instructions (bit-operations).

According to @LPs' comment (and after some thought), this looks like PIC-MCU (you did not state the CPU used). The `bit` type tells the compiler the addresses of the objects (`ZERO`, etc.) address single bits in the "RAM" (`STATUS` is actually a CPU register memory-mapped) address space. The bit-number is packed into the lower 3 bits (bit 0..7) and the byte-address is in the upper bits.

The right side of the `@` calculats this bit-address: (8 bits/byte, hence the multiplication) and bit-number (lower 3 bits, hence the addition. Alternatively one could use bit-operators (identical result):

```
static volatile bit IRP @ ((unsigned)&STATUS << 3) | 7;
...
```

I'm very sure, `@` and `bit` are explained in the compiler documentation.

Note that the bit-type is actually violating the C standard, as this mandates the smallest addressable type to be `char` with at least 8 bits and `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Comment: Hi Tech sounds more like Microchip MCUs

Comment: @LPs: Hmm... you might be right (long time not looked at PIC SR), the RP bits for the RAM-Pages. But PIC does not allow to bit-address memory (please read my edit).

Comment: I am sure this is not explained in the Hi Tech C manual. I searched for it. I don't get the multiplication + bit number. Can you explain it?

Comment: And why the downvote?? I hate these dumba**es who downvote without even leaving a comment.

Comment: @tcop: As I wrote: You have 8 bits/byte, so to get the per-bit-address (`bitaddr`), you have to multiply by 8 and add the bit-index. When accessing the bit, the compiler does the reverse: `bit_number = bitaddr % 8; byte_addr = bitaddr / 8;`.

Comment: I really cannot find this any where in the Hi tech C manual. I expected to shift 8 times and add by bit number or something like this.

Comment: @tcop: 1) did you downvote? 2) if yes, please state the rason. "I do not understand" is no reason. 3) I do not understand what your problem in understanding is. If it is **not** in the manual, so be it. And shifting 8 times is a multiplication by 256, but to encode the bit-number in a 8-bit-byte, you only need 3 bits for values 0..7. They could very well have `<< 3` instead of `* 8`, it doesn't matter. Perhaps you should read about binary representation.

Comment: 1) no...I even gave you a positive vote on your comment. Why the hell are you asking me that? 2) what? 3) I don't understand WHY you have to shift the bits 3 times??? Where did you find this info? I said that it would be more logical to shift it 8 time thus multiply by 256 if for some strange reason the compiler reads the upper 8 bits of the UI.

Comment: @tcop: Sorry, no offence, I just had such cases already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88112/discussion-between-olaf-and-tcop).

Comment: @Olaf. I've already voted for your answer but someone has voted negativly so your score is still zero.

Comment: @tcop: I know (with some reps you can see the number of UV/DV, but not who). I get these unjustified DVs from time to time. I seem to have something unpleasant under my fingernails. You cannot become friends with everyone if you prefer to speak a clear language.